# Rails Active Admin - create helper function that wraps around column()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

```
  index as: :reorderable_table do
    column :position
    column :full_name
    column 'Category', &:category_name
    column :avatar do |fm|
      attachment_img(fm.avatar)
    end
    column :banner do |fm|
      attachment_img(fm.banner)
    end
    column :description do |fm|
      fm.description.try(:truncate, 100)
    end
    column :short_profile do |fm|
      fm.short_profile.try(:truncate, 100)
    end
    actions
  end
```

Referring to the code above, even with some custom helper methods, I still find myself having to repeat the `column do apply_logic end` a lot.

How can I write helper methods that wrap around the 'column' function so that my output can become something like this:

```
  index as: :reorderable_table do
    column :position
    column :full_name
    rename_column :category_name, 'Category'
    img_column :avatar
    img_column :banner
    truncate_column :description
    truncate_column :short_profile
    actions
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break up the `IndexTableFor` class in `ActiveAdmin` by placing the following inside an initializer. I placed it in `config/initializers/active_admin_monkey_patches.rb`

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class IndexAsTable < ActiveAdmin::Component
      class IndexTableFor < ::ActiveAdmin::Views::TableFor
        def rename_column str, attr
          column(str) do |obj|
            obj.send(attr)
          end 
        end
        def img_column attr
          column(attr) do |obj|
            attachment_img(obj.send(attr))
          end
        end
        def truncate_column attr, length
          column(attr) do |obj|
            obj.send(attr).try(:truncate, length)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Restart your rails server when making changes, as it is initializer code. Perhaps read the gem source, which in my case was located at

`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@chirails/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb`

I found the location through running

`bundle info activeadmin`